# Exchange 2010 Autodiscover Problem

Tags: exchange-2010, autodiscovery

`https://*****.net/Autodiscover/login.as ... scover.xml` or `https://*****.net/Autodiscover/AutoDiscover.xml`

it is gives error go to these links;

```
Server Error in '/Autodiscover' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /Autodiscover/login.aspx
```

I reset Virtual Directory. but nothing changed.Also , I look to path and don't see login.aspx.

Finally;

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-AutodiscoverVirtualDirectory | fl


 RunspaceId : 86b29bd2-af3b-4952-b49c-3fb175a2c0b9
 Name : Autodiscover (Default Web Site)
 InternalAuthenticationMethods : {Basic, Ntlm, WindowsIntegrated}
 ExternalAuthenticationMethods : {Basic, Ntlm, WindowsIntegrated}
 LiveIdSpNegoAuthentication : False
 WSSecurityAuthentication : False
 LiveIdBasicAuthentication : False
 BasicAuthentication : True
 DigestAuthentication : False
 WindowsAuthentication : True
 MetabasePath : IIS://*****.*****.local/W3SVC/1/ROOT/Autodiscover
 Path : F:\EXCHANGE_V14\ClientAccess\Autodiscover
 ExtendedProtectionTokenChecking : None
 ExtendedProtectionFlags : {}
 ExtendedProtectionSPNList : {}
 Server : *****
 InternalUrl :
 ExternalUrl :
 AdminDisplayName :
 ExchangeVersion : 0.10 (14.0.100.0)
 DistinguishedName : CN=Autodiscover (Default Web ite),CN=HTTP,CN=Protocols,CN=*****,CN=Server
 ative Groups,CN=*****,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,D
 Identity : *****\Autodiscover (Default Web Site)
 Guid : 237aaa6d-ed02-4153-ae24-b01dc4a4c31a
 ObjectCategory : *****.local/Configuration/Schema/ms-Exch-Auto-Discover-Virtual-Directory
 ObjectClass : {top, msExchVirtualDirectory, msExchAutoDiscoverVirtualDirectory}
 WhenChanged : 1/31/2011 4:14:19 AM
 WhenCreated : 1/31/2011 4:14:19 AM
 WhenChangedUTC : 1/31/2011 2:14:19 AM
 WhenCreatedUTC : 1/31/2011 2:14:19 AM
 OrganizationId :
 OriginatingServer : *****.*****.local
 IsValid : True
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,

Comment: Although that could have been phrased a bit friendlier, Pauska is right. If you want an answer to your question, put some effort in it by formatting it correctly and accepting answers to previous questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be better to describe your actual problem - this all looks very normal to me. My Autodiscover is working just fine and I also get a 404 error for `login.aspx` and an XML error for `AutoDiscover.xml` - just because they don't load in a web browser, it doesn't mean Autodiscover is broken.

By far the best way to test Autodiscover is using Outlook (or [testexchangeconnectivity.com](https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/) if you're testing external Autodiscover). In the system tray, hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and right click on the Outlook icon and choose **Test E-mail AutoConfiguration**. If you get any errors, please edit your original question to include them.